# React how to test props passed to component passed as prop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Okay, this might sound complicated but it will be easy if you read the following example. The main purpose of this is to separate the logic from the actual render code. Making the component smaller and (in theory) easier to test.

```
class NameProvider {
    public getName(): Promise<string> {
        return Promise.resolve("Cool name");
    }
}

interface RenderProps {
    name: string;
    onGetNamePress(): void;
}

interface LogicProps {
    nameProvider: NameProvider;
    render: React.ComponentType<RenderProps>
}

function Render({name, onGetNamePress}: RenderProps): React.ReactElement {
    return <>
        <p>{name}</p>
        <button title="Get name!" onClick={onGetNamePress} />
    </>
}

function Logic({nameProvider, render: Render}: LogicProps): React.ReactElement {
    const [name, setName] = React.useState<string>();

    return <Render
        name={name}
        onGetNamePress={fetch}
    />

    async function fetch() {
        setName(await nameProvider.getName());
    }
}
```

Testing the render component is rather easy, but how do I test that the props passed to the render component are correct? Especially after the state changed.

Consider the following:

```
it('fetches the name after the button was pressed', () => {
    const mnp = new MockNameProvider();
    
    render(<Logic
        nameProvider={mnp}
        render={({name, onGetNamePress}) => {
            act(async () => {
                await onGetNamePress();

                expect(name).toBe(mockName);
            })
        }}
    />)
})
```

This will cause an infinite loop, as the state keeps getting changed and the name fetched. I also couldn't imagine how to get the *new* props. This current code will test the old ones to my understanding. So my question is, how do I test if the props are correctly passed (also after updates).

*(Important) Notes:*

- I'm actually writing a react native app, so maybe the issue is specific to [native testing](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-native-testing-library/intro) but I didn't think so.
- This is **not** code from our codebase and just cobbled together. Thus also the `React` prefix, vscode just liked that better in an unsaved file.

Comment: The `render` prop on the `Logic` component isn't used anywhere. What you're trying to test is all internal to the component. You'll want to render the component then interact with the DOM to then assert the expected changes.

Comment: @juliomalves The render prop is used in the `Logic` component at line `3` (starting to count at the component `function` definition). I'm trying to test the props passed the `Render` component, thus "mocking" the rendering and having an easy way to assert if the logic is correct.

Comment: @juliomalves If you look at the `Logic` definition, it's actually the prop being renamed from `render` to `Render`... yeah, I should have given that a different name whoopse. But it is being used.

Comment: You're right, I see it now. Still, what I mentioned in my first comment still stands. Don't pass a component with assertions in it, pass it a regular component then interact with the DOM to then assert the expected changes.

Comment: @juliomalves But I'm trying to separate the logic from the actual rendering...